# Python script to fetch/copy files from WIndows machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am actually developing a script (which runs in linux machine) to fetch particular files from windows machine for every iteration and do some operation based on the file content. So, Is there any pythonic way to do this?
Please help me out with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The idea is just to use `open` to read content and `os` module to copy

Comment: I tried setting up ssh servers in windows and access the files via ssh/scp. It didn't work out. So I'm finding a way in python.

Comment: samba on linux to mount windows machine?

Comment: Is it a windows share? Have you mounted it on your filesystem?

Comment: Windows is separate remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Sure check out the [following module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which accommodates to navigate both on Windows and Linux File Systems with the class '[Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths)' and in particular its 'iterdir', 'glob' and 'rglob' methods.

An alternative is to use the 'os' module, more specifically with '[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)', 'os.fwalk', 'os.scandir' and/or 'os.listdir' (with 'os.walk' and 'os.listdir' available in Python 2.7 too).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

Download and install [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/winsshd-download) server (one of best ssh servers available out there) for windows machine. Run it as an administrator.

Now, from linux machine fetch the contents of any file using ssh and sshpass tools (As a root user).

Ex: `sshpass -p <windows_password> ssh <windows_name>@<windows_IP> "type path\to\file"`